# Detect who launched COM server

Tags: c++, com

I wrote a simple local (out-of-proc) COM server and I have the following question. Can the server detect who launched him (e.g. a user by starting an executable file directly or a client application by calling `CoCreateInstance` function with `CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER` argument for receiving an object of some class)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have analysed command line of your COM server you can notice that it has **-Embedding** option when it was launched by CoCreateInstance.

If it was launched by user then there's no any options.